# How to configure jboss-eap 6.2 as a service and set Auto-start on CentOS 6.x and Linux1 AMI

Tags: centos6, jboss6.x, amazon-ami

We were using an older version of Jboss 4.x with JDK 5 on CentOS 5.x, this version of Jboss is very old now, even this version is also not supported by RedHat now.

Now we are upgrading to `jboss-eap 6.2` and `jdk1.7.0_60` and `CentOS 6.x` in UAT and AWS Linux1 AMI for Production, I have installed Jboss 6.2 in `/var/lib/jboss-eap-6.2` folder. Necessary modification in the code are already done, application is working fine and Jboss is running as a process using below command.

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
```

Below command shows that process is running on port 8080.

```
netstat -aptn | grep LISTEN
```

Please help configure Jboss 6.2 as a service and set Auto-start, when OS starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to Configure Jboss6.2 as Service and configure it as Auto restart. The process is same for CentOS 6.x and AWS Linux1 AMI.

1. Copy files into system directories

a. Copy the modified configuration file to the /etc/jboss-as directory.

```
mkdir /etc/jboss-as

cp /var/lib/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/init.d/jboss-as.conf /etc/jboss-as/
```

Uncomment following line

```
JBOSS_USER=root
```

and add the following line at the end of this file.

```
export JBOSS_USER
```

b. Copy the start-up script to the /etc/init.d directory.

```
cp /var/lib/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh /etc/init.d/jboss-62
```

2. Do following changes in /etc/init.d/jboss-62 file

   i)-Set Java Home `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60 export JAVA_HOME`

   ii)-Set JBOSS Home `JBOSS_HOME=/var/lib/jboss-eap-6.2 export JBOSS_HOME`

   iii)-Change Configuration xml file name(you may give what ever configuration file name you are using)

   JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone-full.xml

   iv)-Add "-b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0" in the following line, so that binding is set for every IP address on this system

   `daemon --user $JBOSS_USER LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1`
   `JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement`
   `0.0.0.0 -c $JBOSS_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &`
3. Add the start-up script as a service.

Add the new jboss-as-standalone.sh ( i.e jboss-62 ) service to list of automatically started services, using the chkconfig command.

```
chkconfig --add jboss-62
```

4. Start the service.

   `service jboss-62 start`
5. Make the service to start automatically when you restart your
   server.

   `chkconfig jboss-62 on`
6. Restart the service

   `service jboss-62 restart`

Now Jboss6.2 configuration as a Service as Auto restart is complete.
Reboot os and check that service is running. Run below command ot verify that service is running on port 8080

`netstat -aptn | grep LISTEN | grep 8080`